# "Range out of order in character class" regex error in electron but not chrome

Tags: electron

So this is a somewhat exploratory question, and maybe just a bug. Our bundle includes a package called AutoLinker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/autolinker) which makes some complex regexes to turn raw strings into strings with `<a>` anchor tags in them.

The bundle executes just fine in a regular chrome tab for me but when this is executed in an electron BrowserWindow I it causes the error below to happen.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?:[0-9Ù -Ù©Û°-Û¹ß€-ß‰à¥¦-à¥¯à§¦-à§¯à©¦-à©¯à«¦-à«¯à­¦-à­¯à¯¦-à¯¯à±¦-à±¯à³¦-à³¯àµ¦-àµ¯à·¦-à·¯à¹-à¹™à»-à»™à¼ -à¼©á€-á‰á‚-á‚™áŸ -áŸ©á -á ™á¥†-á¥á§-á§™áª€-áª‰áª-áª™á­-á­™á®°-á®¹á±€-á±‰á±-á±™ê˜ -ê˜©ê£-ê£™ê¤€-ê¤‰ê§-ê§™ê§°-ê§¹ê©-ê©™ê¯°-ê¯¹ï¼-ï¼™]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9Ù -Ù©Û°-Û¹ß€-ß‰à¥¦-à¥¯à§¦-à§¯à©¦-à©¯à«¦-à«¯à­¦-à­¯à¯¦-à¯¯à±¦-à±¯à³¦-à³¯àµ¦-àµ¯à·¦-à·¯à¹-à¹™à»-à»™à¼ -à¼©á€-á‰á‚-á‚™áŸ -áŸ©á -á ™á¥†-á¥á§-á§™áª€-áª‰áª-áª™á­-á­™á®°-á®¹á±€-á±‰á±-á±™ê˜ -ê˜©ê£-ê£™ê¤€-ê¤‰ê§-ê§™ê§°-ê§¹ê©-ê©™ê¯°-ê¯¹ï¼-ï¼™]{1,3}/: 
Range out of order in character class
```

Maybe BrowserWindow could be configured differently and I'm missing something? Maybe an electron bug. Anyway just throwing it out there for any leads / opinions / advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the UTF-8 charset in your HTML. If you using the Electron, enable it in index.html file

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```